# Fix webpack config to not output non minified version of sass files

Tags: webpack

My webpack is outputting non minified versions that include the webpack bootstrapping in addition to the minified versions. I'd like it to just compile the sass and output the minified versions:

```js
const glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");

const entryPlus = require('webpack-entry-plus');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");


const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

let isProduction = false;

const entryFiles = [

    {
        entryFiles: glob.sync('./vue-spas/**/app.js'),
        outputName(item) {
            return item.replace('vue-spas/', 'spa/').replace('/app.js','.min.js');
        },
    },
    {
        entryFiles: glob.sync('./styles/portal/manifests/**/*.scss'),
        outputName(item) {
            return item.replace('styles/portal/manifests/', 'css/').replace('.scss', '');
        },
    },
    {
        entryFiles: glob.sync('./js/konstructs/**/*.js'),
        outputName: '/js/main.min.js'
    },
    {
        entryFiles: glob.sync('./js/components/**/*.js'),
        outputName(item){
            return item.replace('.js', '.min.js');
        }
    }

]


module.exports = function(env, argv){
    if (argv.mode === "production") {
        isProduction = true;
    }

    return {
        entry: entryPlus(entryFiles),
    
        output: {
            filename: '[name]',

            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        externals: {
            vue: 'Vue'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: "vue-loader",
                    options: {
                        preserveWhitespace: false,
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // Apply rule for .sass, .scss or .css files
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            
                    // Set loaders to transform files.
                    // Loaders are applying from right to left(!)
                    // The first loader will be applied after others
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                            
                    
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].min.css'
            }),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    "process.env": {
                        NODE_ENV: isProduction ? '"production"' : '""'
                    }
                })
        
        ],
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [
                new UglifyJSPlugin({
                    cache: true,
                    parallel: true
                  }),
                  // enable the css minification plugin
                  new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
            ]
        }
    
    }
}
```

The output that I get is ideal for everything except my SASS files:

```
/root
----/css
-------/themeone
-------/themeone.min.css
-------/themetwo
-------/themetwo.min.css
```

Trying to figure out where I'm going wrong with duplicating the output of the SASS generated files, with the non *.min.css being unecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who is experiencing the same issue. Apparently this is just a known issue for webpack 4. It is set to be resolved for webpack 5

[Reference](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/151)

As webpack 5 is not out at the time of me asking this question I resolved this by using a plugin to do some postprocessing of the output folder and targetting specific file types to be removed. This certainly isn't the most elegant way to accomplish this, but it does solve the problem that happens when the default webpack 4 process runs.

My webpack.config.js file solution:

```js
const glob = require('glob');
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");

const entryPlus = require('webpack-entry-plus');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");


const RemovePlugin = require('remove-files-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const TerserJSPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");


let isProduction = false;

const entryFiles = [

    ///..... Other Entry Files
    {//// SASS Themes
        entryFiles: glob.sync('./styles/portal/manifests/**/*.scss'),
        outputName(item) {
            console.log(item);
            return item.replace('styles/portal/manifests/', 'css/portal/').replace('.scss', '');
        },
    }
    /////.......... Other Entry Files

]


module.exports = function(env, argv){
    if (argv.mode === "production") {
        isProduction = true;
    }

    return {
        entry: entryPlus(entryFiles),
    
        output: {
            filename: '[name]',

            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
        },
        externals: {
            vue: 'Vue'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: "vue-loader",
                    options: {
                        preserveWhitespace: false,
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    // Apply rule for .sass, .scss or .css files
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            
                    // Set loaders to transform files.
                    // Loaders are applying from right to left(!)
                    // The first loader will be applied after others
                    use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
                            
                    
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: '[name].min.css'
            }),
            new RemovePlugin({
       
                after: {
                    test: [
                        {
                            folder: 'dist/css',
                            method: (filePath) => {
                                return !(new RegExp(/\.css$/, 'm').test(filePath));
                            },
                            recursive: true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                    "process.env": {
                        NODE_ENV: isProduction ? '"production"' : '""'
                    }
                })
        
        ],
        optimization: {
            minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({})],
          },
    
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone else. I'll try and update when webpack 5 comes out.